# failed to render instance library not loaded [macOS]

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoapods, swiftdate

I am getting the above error while trying to implement `@IBDesignable` in my class. I have tried all the online solutions like deleting derived date updating pod etc. But nothing is working for me.
I am using `cocoapods version 1.2.1`
**This is how my class looks**

```
import Cocoa

@IBDesignable class ClassName: NSView {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit();
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        commonInit();
    }

    func commonInit(){
        wantsLayer = true;
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.darkGray.cgColor

    }
}
```

**This is how my podfile looks**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :osx, ’10.11’

target 'ProjectName’ do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'SwiftDate', '~> 4.1.7’

end
```

**This is the screenshot of the error i am getting**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my target project i went to `Runpath Search Paths` and edited `@loader_path/Frameworks` to `@loader_path/../Frameworks`. Doing this fixed the issue for me.